# MonoTouch testing of threads

Tags: .net, testing, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a class that does certain functions in a different thread. I want to test this class in my MonoTouch app. so I added a test fixture to the test projects. I found that MonoTouch does not wait for the Test to finish, it just says it is "successful" while the test case is still running. An example of the case is below:

```
[Test]
public void ThreadTest()
{
    Timer ApplicationTimer = new Timer {Enabled = true, Interval = 2500};
    ApplicationTimer.Elapsed += ApplicationTimer_Tick;
}

private void ApplicationTimer_Tick (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   Assert.Fail("failing"); // by the time the debugger hits this point, the UI already says that all tests passed. which is totally wrong. 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a MonoTouch specific issue - that test would fail in all testrunners.

A test which waits for this async event might look like:

```
        private ManualResetEvent _mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        [Test]
        public void ThreadTest()
        {
            Timer ApplicationTimer = new Timer {Enabled = true, Interval = 2500};
            ApplicationTimer.Elapsed += ApplicationTimer_Tick;
            if (!_mre.WaitOne(3000))
            {
                Assert.Fail("Timer was not signalled");
            }
        }

        private void ApplicationTimer_Tick (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _mre.Set();             
        }
```

But you'd have to be very careful in writing this sort of test to make sure you didn't lock threads, reuse objects across tests, etc.